# Show image on Click listener of Grid view ANdroid

Tags: android, gridview

I have grid view in my android app and i want that when i click on one of the image in grid view it shows that image in full view.

Currently it shows the position of the image when click on it.

Here is code

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Here is ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
        //imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(mThumbIds[position]));
        return imageView;
    }


    public String[] mThumbIds = new String[]{
            "http://192.168.1.4/comic_app/index.php?id=1",
            "http://192.168.1.4/comic_app/index.php?id=67",
            "http://192.168.1.4/comic_app/index.php?id=4",
            "http://192.168.1.4/comic_app/index.php?id=89",
            "http://192.168.1.4/comic_app/index.php?id=98",
            "http://192.168.1.4/comic_app/index.php?id=23",
            "http://192.168.1.4/comic_app/index.php?id=45",
    };
}
```

How to show image on click of that image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/implement-onitemclicklistener-for.html - this tutorial will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem i just replace this line

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
```

with this

```
Picasso.with(imageAdapter.mContext).load(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
```

Now working fine....

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `BitMap` to the other activity in the following way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CameraPreviewActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
gridItem = gridItems.get(position);
bitmap = gridItem.getImage();
image_title = gridItem.getImageTitle();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
extras.putString(IMAGE_TITLE,image_title);
extras.putByteArray(IMAGE, bos.toByteArray());
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code will go inside your `gridview.setOnItemClickListener`.

And in the next activity obtain the image using the below code.

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra(IMAGE);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the position of clicked item to next screen

```
     // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
     // passing array index
     i.putExtra("id", position);
     startActivity(i);
```

Then in FullImageActivity you can get the image position and display it as

```
 // get intent data
 Intent i = getIntent();

 // Selected image id
 int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
 ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
 imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
```

For more reference you can visit the below link:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/